# What is the "Che" in fonts BatangChe, DotumChe, GulimChe, GungsuhChe, etc

Tags: fonts

There is a font **Batang** and a font **BatangChe**, likewise for other Korean fonts Dotum, Gulim, and Gungsuh. But what is the difference? What does the "Che" indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, finally, here we are:

http://blog.korea.net/?p=7505

The "Che" variants are monospace, which is more noticeable with Latin letters than with Hangeul.

Comment: Right, at least they are intended to be monospaced (they aren't, in the true sense of the word though). For some related amusement, try Google Translate with the Korean names of the fonts. Here's a preview:

 - 굴림 (Gulim): "Tahoma" 
 - 굴림체 (GulimChe): "Courier" (a monospaced font!)
 - 돋움 (Dotum): "Arial" 
 - 돋움체 (DotumChe): "Tahoma" (huh?!?)